# T-Sql Combining Multiple Columns into One Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I combine the calculation date columns all into one column?  What's the SQL function to make this happen? They rest of the fields are distinct values based on the calculation date.   I only need the distinct values associated with the dates.

[image]

***EDIT***

I tried the `ISNULL` and `COALESCE` functions and this is not what I'm looking for because it still brings back all the values for both of the dates.  I only need the data as of the date for select accounts.  I don't want the data for both dates on the same account.

I also tried the Select Distinct and it's not working for me.

Comment: As commented, what are your expected results?  Please edit your question accordingly -- don't just say it doesn't work, say why -- show the results you have now and the ones you intend to have instead.  We'd like to help if you supply enough information for us to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use COALESCE

```
SELECT COALESCE(Calculation_Date, Calculation_Date)
FROM tableName
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Only problem is the performance on the tables is very slow.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Maybe you need an index on column?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming only 1 of them will ever have a value, one option is to use `coalesce`:

```
select coalesce(date1, date2) 
from yourtable
```

Comment: This won't work because it brings back all the values for for both of the dates.  I only want the distinct values associated with the dates.

Comment: @Showstopper -- then add `distinct` to the `select` list?  If that doesn't work, please edit your question with your expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only two columns, an alternative is to use `ISNULL`:

```
SELECT ISNULL(FIRST_CALCULATION_DATE, SECOND_CALCULATION_DATE) AS ActualCalculationDate
FROM TheTable
```

You should receive the same results as for COALESCE, but it is interesting to know that there are some [subtle differences](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull) between them when it comes to determining result type.

Comment: This won't work because it brings back all the values for for both of the dates.  I only want the distinct values associated with the dates.